# CREATE FUNCTION failed because T-SQL and CLR types for return value do not match

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, clr

I have created a .Net assembly that returns a set of records. When I create a function in SQL Server, I get the message

**CREATE FUNCTION for ...failed because T-SQL and CLR types for return value do not match.**

I am a bit lost, does anyone have a clue what is going wrong? This is my assembly:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.Net.Json;
namespace SQLHttpRequest
{
    public partial class HTTPFunctions
    {

       public class mailBox
       {
           public bool Expanded { get; set; }
           public string ID { get; set; }
           public string Name { get; set; }
           public string ParentID { get; set; }
           public int ChildFolderCount { get; set; }
           public int UnreadItemCount { get; set; }
           public int TotalItemCount { get; set; }
       }

       public static void FillRow(object mailBoxObject
           , out SqlBoolean Expanded
           , out SqlString ID
           , out SqlString Name
           , out SqlString ParentID
           , out SqlInt32 ChildFolderCount
           , out SqlInt32 UnreadItemCount
           , out SqlInt32 TotalItemCount
            )
        {
           var mb = (mailBox)mailBoxObject;
           Expanded = mb.Expanded;
           ID = mb.ID;
           Name = mb.Name;
           ParentID = mb.ParentID;
           ChildFolderCount = mb.ChildFolderCount;
           UnreadItemCount = mb.UnreadItemCount;
           TotalItemCount = mb.TotalItemCount;
      }

    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction(DataAccess = DataAccessKind.Read
            , TableDefinition = "Expanded BIT, ID NVARCHAR(100),Name NVARCHAR(max),ParentID NVARCHAR(max),ChildFolderCount INT, UnreadItemCount INT, TotalItemCount INT"
            , FillRowMethodName = "FillRow")]
    public static List<mailBox> GetMailFolders(string WellKnownFolderName, string FolderID, string UserID, string password)
       {
           List<mailBox> mbs = ReadFolder(WellKnownFolderName, UserID, password);
           // Method ReadFolder Fills the mbs List
           return mbs;
        }
   }
}
```

The assembly receives some parameters and returns a List of mail folders.  The assembly is succesfully created in SQL Server:

```
 CREATE ASSEMBLY SQLHttpRequest
 FROM N'C:\...\SQLHttpRequest.dll'
 WITH PERMISSION_SET=UNSAFE;
```

When I try to create the function

```
    CREATE FUNCTION dbo.usp_GetMailFolders(
         @WellKnownFolderName  nvarchar(max),
         @FolderID    nvarchar(max),
         @UserID        nvarchar(max),
         @password      nvarchar(max)
    )
    RETURNS TABLE
    (
        Expanded BIT,
        ID NVARCHAR(100),
        Name NVARCHAR(100),
        ParentID NVARCHAR(100),
        ChildFolderCount int,
        UnreadItemCount int,
        TotalItemCount int
    )
    AS
    EXTERNAL NAME SQLHttpRequest.[SQLHttpRequest.HTTPFunctions].GetMailFolders;
```

I receive the follwing error:

**CREATE FUNCTION for "usp_GetMailFolders" failed because T-SQL and CLR types for return value do not match.**

Can anyone spot what I am missing here?

Thanks in advance for your response!

Comment: I'm not that into `C#`, but I believe you'll have to implement the `IEnumerable` interface: (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131103.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Hi Nicky, thanks for your response. From MSDN I found that the List<> class implements IEnumerable:    public class List<T> : IList<T>, ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IList, ICollection, IEnumerable

Comment: not sure but the public static GetMailFolders has no FolderID and the sql function does. Maybe that can be an issue ?

Comment: Hi Guido, the FolderID is an input parameter to the function. The output uses ID. The latter is defined both in FillRow and in TableDefinition of GetMailFolders. IMO this is correct.

Comment: Not for nothing, but what did visual studio come up with as a deployment script for your function?

Comment: Hi Ben, good point: I checked the deployement script, and it came up with the same script. If I try to publish the TVF, then Visual Studio runs into the same error message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to change signature of function GetMailFolders to IEnumerable.

public static IEnumerable GetMailFolders(string WellKnownFolderName, string FolderID, string UserID, string password)

I looked again, and it seems to me to try to put nvarchar instead of varchar in the code to create the tool.

Comment: Hi Nenad, the List<> class already implements the IEnumarable interface, so this should not be necessary. I did give it a try however, but to no avail.

Comment: In .Net a String contains unicode characters and is mapped to n(var)char in SQL Server: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092.aspx The varchar has no mapping to a .Net type.

Answer (score 1):

Change `GetMailFolders` function's return type from `List<mailBox>` to `IEnumerable`.

As [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131103(v=sql.110).aspx) states:

> Beginning with SQL Server 2005, SQL Server extends the functionality of table-valued functions by allowing you to define a table-valued function in any managed language. Data is returned from a table-valued function through an IEnumerable or IEnumerator object.

After rebuild, don't forget to drop and recreate the assembly in database.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you all turned out to be right:

```
public static IEnumerable GetMailFolders
```

did the the trick. In my previous attempts (see comment tot Nenad's answer) I used the

```
IEnumerable<mailbox>
```

instead of

```
IEnumerable
```

Thanks all for your comments and answers!